# Updating a table with mutliple criteria from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have inherited a database that contains among others, two relevant tables, one for Clients and one for Matters. Clients may have more than one matter, and these two tables are linked by a Client ID field.

As part of a de-identifying process, seven years after a file has been closed we are required to remove the first names, last names and date of birth of clients in the Clients table, however we want to otherwise retain the record so we are able to keep track of what work we have done in the past.

I want to create an update query that will replace the identifying data with de-identified data when a client fulfills these conditions:

- The client has no matters that are currently open (i.e. that have a 'null' in
  the file closure date field in the Matters table).
- The client has no matters that have closed less than seven years ago.
- The client has one or more matters that have closed more than seven years ago.

However I am unable to figure out how I can get this to work. Setting up an update query that would update the info in the Clients table if it has a corresponding matter that is older than seven years seems possible, but I can't figure out how to do it in such a way that wouldn't also update the info if the client still has matters open, or has matters younger than seven years. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

To expand further, so far my query involves two tables, `Clients` and `Matters`. The file closure date is in `Matters` and the client's identifying details are in `Clients`. So as far as I understand, it's more of a join problem than a criteria problem.

```
Client | MatterID | MatterClosureDate
-------|----------|------------------
Alice  | 1        | 2008
Bruce  | 2        | 2009
Carrol | 3        | 2009
Bruce  | 250      | 2012
```

to illustrate, there are four relevant results from the two tables. Alice and Carrol are both clients who have no matters that are still open or recently closed, however Bruce has one matter that should disqualify him. At the moment though my query is not sophisticated enough to realize this, and returns this:

```
Client | MatterID | MatterClosureDate
-------|----------|------------------
Alice  | 1        | 2008
Bruce  | 2        | 2009
Carrol | 3        | 2009
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using correlated subqueries matched row-wise to each *ClientID* for each listed condition:

```
SELECT c.FirstName, m.MatterID, m.MatterClosureDate
FROM Clients c
INNER JOIN Matters m ON c.ID = m.ClientID

WHERE 
   (SELECT Count(*) FROM Matters sub 
    WHERE sub.ClientID = c.ID
    AND sub.MatterClosureDate IS NULL) = 0
AND
   (SELECT Count(*) FROM Matters sub 
    WHERE sub.ClientID = c.ID
    AND sub.MatterClosureDate > Year(Date()) - 7) = 0
AND
  (SELECT Count(*) FROM Matters sub 
   WHERE sub.ClientID = c.ID
   AND sub.MatterClosureDate <= Year(Date()) - 7) > 0;

-- FirstName    MatterID    MatterClosureDate
-- Alice        1           2008
-- Carrol       3           2009
```

And for the update query, convert above `SELECT` into `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE Clients c
SET c.FirstName = 'XXXXX', 
    c.LastName = 'XXXXX',
    c.DOB = NULL 

WHERE 
  (SELECT Count(*) FROM Matters sub 
   WHERE sub.ClientID = c.ID
   AND sub.MatterClosureDate IS NULL) = 0
AND
  (SELECT Count(*) FROM Matters sub 
   WHERE sub.ClientID = c.ID
   AND sub.MatterClosureDate > Year(Date()) - 7) = 0
AND
  (SELECT Count(*) FROM Matters sub 
   WHERE sub.ClientID = c.ID
   AND sub.MatterClosureDate <= Year(Date()) - 7) > 0;
```

Alternatively, you can use Access' domain aggregate, `DCount()`:

```
UPDATE Clients c    
SET c.FirstName = 'XXXXX', 
       c.LastName = 'XXXXX',
       c.DOB = NULL 

WHERE     
    DCount("*", "Matters", "ClientID = " & c.ID & " 
           AND MatterClosureDate IS NULL") = 0
AND
    DCount("*", "Matters", "ClientID = " & c.ID & " 
           AND MatterClosureDate  > Year(Date()) - 7") = 0
AND
    DCount("*", "Matters", "ClientID = " & c.ID & " 
           AND MatterClosureDate  <= Year(Date()) - 7") > 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks extremely helpful. I'll give it a shot and update with any progress.

Comment: Finally got it to work (in the select query for now) thank you! `MatterClosureDate` being in a _dd/mm/yyyy_ format did not play nice with the `> Year(Date() - 7)` expression, and changing it to `Year(MatterClosureDate)` returned an 'undefined fuction 'sub.Year' in expression' error. I had to remove the `Year()` from the expression and multiply the 7 by 365, which is inelegant, but being off by a fraction of a day is not a major problem.

Comment: Great! Glad it worked. And since `Year()` is a function, it should be `Year(sub.MatterClosureDate)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `< #9/14/2009# And Is Not Null` in the criteria on *file closure date* field

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this doesn't quite solve my problem. While it accurately picks out clients who have closed cases older than seven years, it doesn't discriminate between clients with _only_ closed cases older than seven years and those who still have open (or recently closed) cases.